# 'Size of array' template parameter not determined by the visual studio compiler (but determined by gcc) during template parameter substitution

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way for the Visual Studio compiler to determine the template parameter M without passing the size of the array as a template parameter to a templatized function like how gcc can determine?

To give an example -

```
template<unsigned M>
void multiply(
 double A[M][M],
 double B[M][M]
)
{
..........
}
```

A and B are arrays in the above example. So for the above example, in gcc if you call the above function as `multiply(A, B);` the code compiles successfully whereas in visual studio you get a compiler error - "no overloaded function found".

But in visual studio only if you call the above function as `multiply<M>(A, B);` where M is the size of arrays A and B, the code compiles successfully.

So basically my question is that is there a way to call the function as `multiply(A, B);` successfully in visual studio without passing the template parameter 'M'?

Tried calling the function 'multiply' as `multiply(A, B);` in visual studio and expected it to work but it did not.

Comment: I saw this question yesterday.

Comment: Your assertions about the behavior of GCC and MSVC are (generally) wrong. Please show a [mre] of the code that you actually try to compile. In particular the behavior will obviously depend on the types of `A` and `B`.

Comment: In C++, using `type[N]` as input parameter is very problematic. Just use something else like `std::array`

Comment: Arrays generally decay to pointers when passed as parameters. Is the decay supposed to happen before or after template deduction?

Comment: @BoP On the argument it happens for the purpose of deduction before any deduction if the function parameter is not a reference, and not at all otherwise. It always happens on the parameter before any deduction. Therefore OP's approach (with some reasonable assumptions) should actually be fine.

Comment: Pass the arrays by reference, that will allow the compiler to deduce their size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double A[M][M]` in a parameter is not an array, it's a pointer. Use a reference to an array, then `M` will be determined:

```
template<unsigned M>
void multiply(
  double (&A)[M][M],
  double (&B)[M][M]
) {
}

int main() {
  double a[2][2]{};
  multiply(a, a);
}
```

Comment: But the way OP passes the 2D arrays - like `double A[M][M]` - should decay to `double (*A)[M]`. It still has `M` in it - why Visual Studio compiler cannot deduce it?